# why can't i include a static library into a cpp file?

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Is there a way to #include "library.a" or it's .so or it's .o inside a cpp or cc file?

I would like to do this because I am using this file inside another file.

Comment: "because I am using this file inside another file" is not a reasonable rationale. What is the wider goal that you are trying to accomplish? I suggest finding yourself a chatroom, which would be better suited to this sort of conversation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#include` is for C++ code.

`.a`, `.so` and `.o` files are not C++ code.

It's more likely that you want to `#include` a C++ header file (typically ending in `.h` or `.hpp`), and *link* an object file.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the Visual C++ compiler, using `#pragma comment(lib, "libname")`- and the similarity is somewhat dubious. However you will have to discover any alternatives for your own favourite compiler.

Comment: Boost uses this to implement their auto-linking feature. AFAIK there is no simmilar functionality on other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

`#include` is used for telling the *compiler* about the functions from a library which you will call in your code, that is to say it includes C++ code. Generally this takes the form of header files which have the function declarations in them.

.a and .so and .o files are compliled code which can be linked into your compiled code using the *linker*.

**Edit:** there's an introduction about compiling and linking [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html)

Answer (score 1):

The `#include` statement basically just includes other source code into the current file. That being said, a static library is not source code and cannot be included in this manner. Static (and shared) libraries are instead *linked* into the project after all the compiling is done.

What you have to do is to include a file containing prototypes to the functions you are going to be using. This way the compiler knows it is there and the linker will sort out the rest.

For more information on how to create and link static/shared libraries, check out [this](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

It simply doesn't make sense.

You include the library's code at compile time by linking it.

Normally there's a header file for the library you can include.

Comment: Sorry, thats what I meant to say.
During the process of compilation.

Comment: No, it's during the process of linking.

Comment: I know, but in my opinion, the linking process belongs to the whole compilation cycle, right?

Comment: You mean the build cycle, which includes compilation and linking: two separate phases.

Comment: Call it "at build time" then.. compilation is only one of the stages you go through to convert C++ code into an executable module.

Comment: is there a way to link a .so or .a file inside a .cpp file?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?